# How to correctly use namespace with xpath in Java

Tags: java, xml, xpath

How do we resolve the exception: "XPathStylesheetDOM3Exception: Prefix must resolve to a namespace: ns3" in Java?

---

What we are trying to achieve is to get the value of errorid in the following xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns3:receive xmlns:ns3="urn:xxx:xxx:xxx:xxx:xxx" xmlns="http://xxx/" xmlns:ns2="urn:xxx:xxx:xxx:xxx">
    <info>
        <identification>xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx</identification>
        <service>tax</service>
        <transactiontime>2017-04-24T12:00:00.146+02:00</transactiontime>
        <answer>
            <errorstructure>
                <errorid>1234</errorid>
                <errortext>Closed</errortext>
            </errorstructure>
        </answer>
    </info>
</ns3:receive>
```

To achieve this, we have the following lines of code, where we use namespace and xpath to get the value of errorid from the xml file. Do notice that we haven't included serviceResponse, but we have checked whether it is correct format.

```
public void function() {
    try {
        // our XML file for this example
        File xmlFile = new File("{name}.xml");
        //Use method to convert XML string content to XML Document object
        final Document doc = convertStringToXMLDocument( serviceResponse );
        XPath xPath1 = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        xPath1.setNamespaceContext(new NamespaceContext() {
            @Override
            public String getNamespaceURI(String prefix) {
                return doc.lookupNamespaceURI(prefix);
            }
            @Override
            public String getPrefix(String namespaceURI) {
                return doc.lookupPrefix(namespaceURI);
            }
            @Override
            public Iterator getPrefixes(String namespaceURI) {
                return null;
            }
        });
        Node errorcode = (Node) xPath1.evaluate("/ns3:receive/infor/answer/errorstructure[1]/errorid/text()", doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
        LOGGER.info("TESTING ERROR CODE : " + errorcode);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        serviceResponse = e.getMessage();
    }
}

private static Document convertStringToXMLDocument(String xmlString)
{
    //Parser that produces DOM object trees from XML content
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

    //API to obtain DOM Document instance
    DocumentBuilder builder = null;
    try
    {
        //Create DocumentBuilder with default configuration
        builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);

        //Parse the content to Document object
        Document doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlString)));
        return doc;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

In our understanding, set name space context should fix this error, and as it clearly doesn't, we are finding it difficult to fix this exception. Anyone who can figure out why we receive this exception?

---

**StackTrace**

```
com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.domapi.XPathStylesheetDOM3Exception: Prefix must resolve to a namespace: ns3
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.compiler.XPathParser.errorForDOM3(XPathParser.java:667)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.compiler.Lexer.mapNSTokens(Lexer.java:641)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.compiler.Lexer.tokenize(Lexer.java:268)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.compiler.Lexer.tokenize(Lexer.java:99)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.compiler.XPathParser.initXPath(XPathParser.java:116)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.XPath.<init>(XPath.java:178)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.XPath.<init>(XPath.java:268)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathImpl.eval(XPathImpl.java:189)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathImpl.evaluate(XPathImpl.java:271)
    at dk.skat.rsu.b2b.sample.test.modtagMomsAngivelse(test.java:262)
    at dk.skat.rsu.b2b.sample.mvc.ServiceTestAction.execute(ServiceTestAction.java:62)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.ExecuteAction.execute(ExecuteAction.java:58)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.AbstractExecuteAction.execute(AbstractExecuteAction.java:67)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.ActionCommandBase.execute(ActionCommandBase.java:51)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:191)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.generic.LookupCommand.execute(LookupCommand.java:305)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:191)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor.process(ComposableRequestProcessor.java:283)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:462)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:852)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1650)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:219)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:530)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:347)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:256)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:708)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:626)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
--------------- linked to ------------------
javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException: com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.domapi.XPathStylesheetDOM3Exception: Prefix must resolve to a namespace: ns3
        at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathImpl.evaluate(XPathImpl.java:285)
        at dk.skat.rsu.b2b.sample.test.modtagMomsAngivelse(test.java:262)
        at dk.skat.rsu.b2b.sample.mvc.ServiceTestAction.execute(ServiceTestAction.java:62)
        at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.ExecuteAction.execute(ExecuteAction.java:58)
        at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.AbstractExecuteAction.execute(AbstractExecuteAction.java:67)
        at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.ActionCommandBase.execute(ActionCommandBase.java:51)
        at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:191)
        at org.apache.commons.chain.generic.LookupCommand.execute(LookupCommand.java:305)
        at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:191)
        at org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor.process(ComposableRequestProcessor.java:283)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:462)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:852)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1650)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:206)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:190)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:168)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:166)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:219)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:126)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:530)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:347)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:256)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:247)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:140)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:382)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:708)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:626)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.domapi.XPathStylesheetDOM3Exception: Prefix must resolve to a namespace: ns3
        at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.compiler.XPathParser.errorForDOM3(XPathParser.java:667)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.compiler.Lexer.mapNSTokens(Lexer.java:641)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.compiler.Lexer.tokenize(Lexer.java:268)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.compiler.Lexer.tokenize(Lexer.java:99)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.compiler.XPathParser.initXPath(XPathParser.java:116)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.XPath.<init>(XPath.java:178)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.XPath.<init>(XPath.java:268)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathImpl.eval(XPathImpl.java:189)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathImpl.evaluate(XPathImpl.java:271)
        ... 47 more
```

Comment: By returning null from `getPrefixes`, you are violating the contract of NamespaceContext.  Try returning `Arrays.asList(doc.lookupPrefix(namespaceURI)).iterator()`.

Comment: @VGR, thank you for your answer. Unfortunately your answer did not resolve the error, and the exception still occurs

Comment: Instead of calling doc.lookupNamespaceURI and doc.lookupPrefix, call `doc.getDocumentElement().lookupNamespaceURI` and `doc.getDocumentElement().lookupPrefix`, respectively.  `ns3` is defined in an element, not on the document object.  (However, your XPath will not match `info` because that element has a default namespace which is not empty.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you only need to extract the errorid, for the structure of the provided xml you can do:

```
String errorId = (String) xPath1.evaluate("*/info/answer/errorstructure/errorid", doc, XPathConstants.STRING);
```

Edit:

Adding the entire class I tested with:

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test test = new Test();
    String serviceResponse = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n" +
        "<ns3:receive xmlns:ns3=\"urn:xxx:xxx:xxx:xxx:xxx\" xmlns=\"http://xxx/\" xmlns:ns2=\"urn:xxx:xxx:xxx:xxx\">\n" +
        "    <info>\n" +
        "        <identification>xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx</identification>\n" +
        "        <service>tax</service>\n" +
        "        <transactiontime>2017-04-24T12:00:00.146+02:00</transactiontime>\n" +
        "        <answer>\n" +
        "            <errorstructure>\n" +
        "                <errorid>1234</errorid>\n" +
        "                <errortext>Closed</errortext>\n" +
        "            </errorstructure>\n" +
        "        </answer>\n" +
        "    </info>\n" +
        "</ns3:receive>";
    test.function(serviceResponse);
}

public void function(String serviceResponse) {
    try {
        // our XML file for this example
        File xmlFile = new File("{name}.xml");
        //Use method to convert XML string content to XML Document object
        final Document doc = convertStringToXMLDocument(serviceResponse);
        XPath xPath1 = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        xPath1.setNamespaceContext(new NamespaceContext() {
                @Override
                public String getNamespaceURI(String prefix) {
                    return doc.lookupNamespaceURI(prefix);
                }

                @Override
                public String getPrefix(String namespaceURI) {
                    return doc.lookupPrefix(namespaceURI);
                }

                @Override
                public Iterator getPrefixes(String namespaceURI) {
                    return null;
                }
            });

        String errorId = (String) xPath1.evaluate("*/info/answer/errorstructure/errorid", doc, XPathConstants.STRING);
        System.out.println("TESTING ERROR CODE : " + errorId);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static Document convertStringToXMLDocument(String xmlString) {
    //Parser that produces DOM object trees from XML content
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

    //API to obtain DOM Document instance
    DocumentBuilder builder = null;
    try {
        //Create DocumentBuilder with default configuration
        builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);

        //Parse the content to Document object
        Document doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlString)));
        return doc;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}}
```

The output is:

> TESTING ERROR CODE : 1234

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not print anything out for us

Comment: Added the entire test I made, it should work correctly. Other then fixing some brackets not closing correctly, I only changed the line I mentioned in the initial answer and added a System.out.println instead of the Logger.info.

Comment: Also, I passed the serviceResponse as a variabile., it was not present in the initial code anywhere.

If in the line "File xmlFile = new File("{name}.xml");" you are trying to read the XML file content, this part is not complete in the initial code.

Comment: You're absolutely correct, i just tried your solution, and it extracted the errorid!

Comment: Do you need assistence with anything else on this issue or can this be accepted as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you get the ns3 error (I'm no DOM expert), but it's going to fail anyway, because in XPath 1.0 the unprefixed names (in `infor/answer/errorstructure[1]/errorid`) will only match no-namespace elements, whereas your document has these elements in namespace `http://xxx/`; there's no way of fixing this with a namespace context because it isn't invoked for unprefixed names.

Comment: Hi Michael, thank you for your message, it is appreciated. Dragos solution (right above this) made it work, and i can now get the errorid of the xml document!